# Edge not visible in JGraphX graph

Tags: java, jgraphx

I am working on JGraphX. I have added an edge between two vertex using insertEdge method of graphComponent. But the edge is not visible. I can see the edge if I save, then close, then open the same file.
Why it is not visible when I added?

If I create an edge for same cell i.e. graph.insertEdge(parent,null, "hasEntity", newCell, newCell), then it is adding the edge to itself i.e. source and target vertex are same. I need not close and open the graph here.

```
mxCell defaultActivityEdge = (mxCell) graph.insertEdge(parentObject, null, "hasActivity", cell3, newCell); 
graph.addCell(defaultActivityEdge); 
defaultActivityEdge.setVisible(true);
graph.clearSelection(); 
graph.refresh()
```

Comment: Show your code pls or sample of your code.

Comment: You will not help from here unless if we see some part of your logic.

Comment: mxCell defaultActivityEdge = (mxCell) graph.insertEdge(parentObject, null, "hasActivity", cell3, newCell);  
graph.addCell(defaultActivityEdge);  
defaultActivityEdge.setVisible(true);graph.clearSelection();  
graph.refresh();

Comment: cell3 is the root cell. newCell is the new cell created. Edge is expected to be created between newCell and cell3 and to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

You need not add the return object of insertEdge() to the graph as a cell. Please have a look at the below sample and correct the same in your code.

```
public class MxGraphSample {

    public static void creategraph() {

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize(frame.getMaximumSize().width,
                frame.getMaximumSize().height);

        final mxGraph graph = new mxGraph();
        Object parent = graph.getDefaultParent();
        graph.getModel().beginUpdate();

        try {
            Object v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "v1", 20, 20, 80, 30);
            Object v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "v2", 120, 70, 80, 30);
            Object v3 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "v3", 220, 70, 80, 30,
                    "fillColor=lightgreen");

            graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "", v1, v2);
            graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "", v1, v3, "strokeColor=lightgreen");

            graph.cellsFolded(new Object[] {v1, v2, v3}, true, true);

            mxCompactTreeLayout layout = new mxCompactTreeLayout(graph);
            layout.setLevelDistance(40);
            layout.setNodeDistance(30);
            layout.setEdgeRouting(false);
            layout.setUseBoundingBox(false);
            layout.execute(graph.getDefaultParent());

        } finally {
            graph.getModel().endUpdate();
        }
        final mxGraphComponent graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(graph);

        graphComponent.setFoldingEnabled(true);

        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(graphComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        creategraph();
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]